# Insert InnoDB ускорение внесения большого объема данных

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb

У меня имеется около 75683 данных, которые вносятся / изменяются раз в минуту, пытаюсь увеличить скорость выполнения данной операции, все пути которые пробовал привели к этому коду

```
$marketsToSet = array();
$marketsBase = array();
echo "foreach markets - ".  microtime(true) . "<br>";

$time = time();
$i = 0;
$e = 0;
foreach ($marketsData as $key => $value) {

    if(!isset($marketsToSet[$e])) $marketsToSet[$e] = array();
    if(!isset($marketsBase[$e])) $marketsBase[$e] = array();

    $marketsToSet[$e][] = $key;
    $marketsToSet[$e][] = $value['e'];
    $marketsToSet[$e][] = $value['f'];
    $marketsToSet[$e][] = $value['i'];
    $marketsToSet[$e][] = $value['v'];
    $marketsToSet[$e][] = $value['b'];
    $marketsToSet[$e][] = $time;
    $marketsToSet[$e][] = 0;
    $marketsBase[$e][] = "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $i++;

    if($i == 8181) {            
        $i = 0;
        $e++;
    }
}

if(count($marketsBase) != 0) {
    echo " set to bd - ".  microtime(true) . "<br>";
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $e; $i++) {
        echo "insert #". $i . "  count rows ". count($marketsBase[$i]) . " - " .  microtime(true) . "<br>";
        dbCon("INSERT INTO `markets` (`id`, `event_id`, `market_id`, `intext`, `val`, `text`, `version`,`del`) VALUES "  . join(", ", $marketsBase[$i]) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `version` = IF(`text` <> VALUES(`text`) OR `val` <> VALUES(`val`) OR `del` <> VALUES(`del`), VALUES(`version`), `version`), `text` = IF(`text` <> VALUES(`text`), VALUES(`text`), `text`), `val` = IF(`val` <> VALUES(`val`), VALUES(`val`), `val`), `del` = IF(`del` <> VALUES(`del`), VALUES(`del`), `del`)", $marketsToSet[$i], hdRel());    
    }
    echo "end set to bd - ".  microtime(true) . "<br>";
}
```

Вот какую информацию по времени имею на выходе

```
foreach markets - 1587878994.2098
set to bd - 1587878994.251
insert #0 count rows 8181 - 1587878994.251
insert #1 count rows 8181 - 1587878995.9705
insert #2 count rows 8181 - 1587878997.5289
insert #3 count rows 8181 - 1587878999.1871
insert #4 count rows 8181 - 1587879000.8133
insert #5 count rows 8181 - 1587879002.8017
insert #6 count rows 8181 - 1587879004.5995
insert #7 count rows 8181 - 1587879006.3541
insert #8 count rows 8181 - 1587879008.4204
insert #9 count rows 8181 - 1587879010.039
insert #10 count rows 2054 - 1587879011.9794
end set to bd - 1587879012.9125
```

Лимит одного запроса insert в моем случае 8181 при большем кол-ве вылезает ошибка.

Доп инфа: hdRel() - функция подключения к  мускулю (по настройкам хостера, покдлючение живет около 10 секунд, по этому приходится каждый раз переподключатся)

```
 function dbCon($a, $b, $c) {
        $d = $c->prepare($a);
        $d->execute($b);
        return $d;
    }
```

Пример $marketsData:

```
$marketsData = array("a09c35efc909141cfe1ebad6d77b663c" => array("e"=> 931, "f"=> 21033819, "i"=> 4, "v" => "3.5", "b"=> "4:5"));
```

Какие еще есть методы, правки, которые мне нужно внести, что бы еще сильнее сжать скорость выполнения данной операции?

Answer (score -1):

Создайте дублирующую MyISAM таблицу и делайте пакетные вставки в неё - это должно работать быстрее.

Сначала truncate table, потом вставка примерно 75683 строк данных и потом перегонка данных из дублирующей таблицы в основную одним запросом:

```
INSERT INTO `markets` (`id`, `event_id`, `market_id`, `intext`, `val`, `text`, `version`,`del`)
SELECT `id`, `event_id`, `market_id`, `intext`, `val`, `text`, `version`,`del` FROM `markets_tmp`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`version` = IF(`text` <> VALUES(`text`) OR `val` <> VALUES(`val`) OR `del` <> VALUES(`del`), VALUES(`version`), `version`), 
`text` = IF(`text` <> VALUES(`text`), VALUES(`text`), `text`), 
`val` = IF(`val` <> VALUES(`val`), VALUES(`val`), `val`), 
`del` = IF(`del` <> VALUES(`del`), VALUES(`del`), `del`)
```

Answer (score -1):

Заключить весь цикл в транзакцию.
На все вставки уйдет меньше секунды.

Еще можно использовать подготовленные выражения по человечески, 1 prepare - много execute(). Но прирост будет небольшой, процентов 5.

Comment: Имеется ввиду все инсерты прогнать в качестве одного? оно не дает мне вставить больше 8181 Values за транзу. Или я как то не так понял

Comment: Имеется в виду т р а н з а к ц и я

Comment: Тогда я не знаю что это, можно ссылочку на почитать пожалуйста, что это есть и  с чем едят. Спасибо.

Comment: ссылочка google.com/search?q=что такое транзакция

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9819330/285587

Comment: Спасибо, добавил  beginTransaction(); и commit, поставил myslam вместо innodb, уменьшилось с 18 секунд до 11, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли еще какие то варианты?